# Android feature module dependency on another module not finding resources

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module

I have my base module(Base), a dynamic feature module(A) and a common module(Common) that is not a a dynamic feature, its a library. 
When I add Common as a dependency of A, I'm able to use classes from it but my build fails because it can't find the resources (error: cannot find symbol R.drawable.myimage) from the Common library.

```
dependencies {
     implementation project(":Common")
     implementation project(':Base')
}
```

Is this a dynamic feature constraint or is something causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `R.id.resource` will only get the resources from the feature module, `com.yourdomain.base.R.id.resource` will reference resources of the base module which has access to the resources of the library module.

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Import your library module (Common) by using

> File --> New --> Import Module

you can always try a

> Invalidate Caches & Restart

(awkwardly solves most issues with Android Studio)

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it didn't work. I posted what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Install SplitCompat in dynamic feature activity**

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
super.onAttach(context)
SplitCompat.install(context)
}
```

You can refer official dynamic delivery documentation

https://github.com/arpitagarwal1301/AndroidHub/issues/8

Comment: I'm getting the error while trying to build not during run time. The linked issue seems to be a run time error?